# WinEdt: Terminate last run

Tags: winedt

The newer versions of winedt are very annoying as they won't run if a previous compilation did not terminate. This requires manual termination which is simple a hurdle to jump.

Is there any way to automatically terminate any running compilation before recompiling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because WinEdt runs TeX compilers in `errorstopmode`, which means that the compilation hangs when an error occurres, waiting for the user's prompt.

You can type `x` to terminate the compilation or `e` to terminate the compilation *and* jump to the source of the error.

As far as I remember, WinEdt has always acted this way.

If you don't like this behavior, you can tell WinEdt to run TeX compilers in `nonstopmode`.

To do that, go to Options -> Execution Modes and check the option "No Interaction" for the compilers you want:

[image]

If you want, you can press the button "Apply to All" to copy all the properties of the compiler to all the others.